# How to scroll to the bottom cell of tableview in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have created a chat view in which I have used tableview, the basic feature of ChatView is to show the latest messages(last cell), But tableView is not scrolling to last index, it's always stuck somewhere in the middle

```
 func scrollToBottom()  {
    let point = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.chatTableView.contentSize.height + 200.0)
            self.chatTableView.setContentOffset(point, animated: true)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5

Hi,you just have to call this line of code after loading table view.

```
  self. chatTableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: lastRowIndex, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: true)
```

(In place of "lastRowIndex", you have to enter index of your last row of tableView. You can use the value of count of your Array that you are using to populate tableView. For example: (yourArray.count - 1))

Comment: This error occurs (Cannot find 'lastRowIndex' in scope)

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
      
      self.chatTableView.reloadData()
      self.chatTableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: lastRowIndex, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: true)
}

Comment: In place of "lastRowIndex", you have to enter index of your last row of tableView. You can use the value of count of your Array that you are using to populate tableView. For example: (yourArray.count - 1)

Comment: @s.Aualkh If you can update your answer, please move your last comment into it ;)   Thanks.

Comment: @s.Aualkh this error now occurs EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xfffffffffffffffc)

Comment: If you are facing a crash then it must be due to index out of range. Make sure to never use static value in IndexPath. For example if your tableView have 5 rows then in indexPath you have to use it like this: IndexPath(row: 4, section:0). 

THis is just an example so I have used static values. You have to use count of array.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) {
        self.scrollToBottom()
    }
}
private func scrollToBottom(){
    let y = self.collectionView.contentSize.height - self.collectionView.btHeight() + self.collectionView.adjustedContentInset.bottom
    self.collectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: y), animated: false)
    if self.loadingView.superview != nil {
        self.loadingView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    
}
```